# iOS How to fix UIButton height in a custom UITableView cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom table view cell with two buttons. The accompanying text has a varying number of lines which affects the height of the cell. This height variations causes the height of the buttons vary. I have tried a lot different things to fix this with no luck. Currently the two buttons are in a stack view and that is in another stack view with the UILabel. I'd like the buttons with a fixed height vertically centered in the cell. What's the best way to do that?

[image]

Comment: What did you use auto-layout or auto-sizing?

Comment: If you are using auto layout then just fix height of button and centre aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Use only *one* stack view - for the buttons.

Constrain your `UIStackView` to the trailing edge of the cell's content view, and constrain it centered Vertically.

Constrain your `UILabel` to the leading edge of the cell's content view, and constrain it centered Vertically.

Also constrain your `UILabel` horizontal-spacing to the `UIStackView`, and edit it to be `>= 8`.

And, the key part, also constrain your `UILabel` Top and Bottom to `>= 4`.

Now, when your label wraps to multiple rows, it will "push the top and bottom", and your stack view holding your buttons will remain vertically centered, but will not "grow in height".

[image]

[image]